# btn-success can't be assigned

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn angular, I want to enable a button upon a function call,
so I've binded this part in the html :

```
<button [disabled]="!enableAdd" class="btn btn-block mb-3"
        [ngClass]="currentClasses">Add new user</button>
```

and used this in the function

```
SetCurrentClasses () {
  this.currentClasses = {
    'btn-success': this.enableAdd
  }
```

how when compiling this error pops up

> Type '{ 'btn-success': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''btn-success'' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

what is very weird is that enableAdded is a type bool, even when I try to

```
'btn-success': true
```

the same error appears...

I really have no clue why.

Comment: Why not just do `this.enableAdd = true` directly in function call?

Comment: it's set by an object status so it needs to be repeated

Comment: have you tried defining the classes object inline: `[ngClass]="{'btn-success': enableAdd}"`? 
Another option would be making it a function call `[ngClass]="getClasses()"` and creating a getClasses method that return your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you passed `currentClasses` to `[ngClass]`, you are effectively passing an object to `[ngClass]` which it doesn't allows. It's just like the `class` attribute in `<button>`, you don't declare it as 'class="{ btn-success:true }"`. That's why it doesn't work.

You can use `[class.disabled]` which is utilizing bootstrap's .disabled class to disable a button instead of angular's [disabled] property.

e.g.

```html
<button [class.disabled]="!enableAdd" class="btn mb btn-success">
   Add new user
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the NgClass property only accepts:
string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added,
Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added,
Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

but not functions, you will need to evaluate that function apart, you can do it on DoCheck() on OnChanges()

I paste you the documentation about it:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass